# What part of speech does the word "but" represent in this case

Tags: parts-of-speech

I am interested in knowing the part of speech (ie. noun, pronoun, adverb, conjunction, etc...) that the word "but" would be in this instance.

> But he has been hampered in his research by the indefensible failure of the State Bar of California to provide the statistics he needs.

I have read elsewhere that "but" almost always represents a conjunction, but in this sentence, it does not seem to conjoin anything.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 'But' can begin a sentence and the context of the previous sentence will demonstrate what is being contrasted. It is still a conjunction when it begins the sentence. What is being 'conjoined' is in the previous sentence.

Comment: I agree with Nigel. Sentences are not required to be autonomous thought.

Comment: In your own sentence (last paragraph of your question), you could replace the comma before 'but' with a full stop. You'd then be using 'but' in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

It is still a conjunction. It is quite common to start a new sentence with a conjunction - to add some extra emphasis.